# Jumpy Safari & Firefox when animating margin-top jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari, margin

I'm trying to accomplish a simple parallax type effect with fixed content in each section as the user scrolls.

Everything scrolls as intended, but in every browser except Chrome the fixed element "movement" by adjusting margin-top is jittery and jumpy and isn't fluid.

Any help with the jitter or maybe a slightly different way to do this would help tremendously. Thank you in advance.

Here is the simplifed code on CodePen
https://codepen.io/mobiusint/pen/OdGavY

```
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="home-parallax" id="home-slide-1">
<div class="home-parallax-bg-1"></div>
<div class="home-parallax-content">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" class="border">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="empty red"></div>
<div class="home-parallax" id="home-slide-2">
<div class="home-parallax-bg-2"></div>
<div class="home-parallax-content">
<div><h1>Alot of content JUMPS in firefox & safari</h1></div>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" class="border">
<p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" class="border">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="home-parallax" id="home-slide-3">
<div class="home-parallax-bg-3"></div>
<div class="home-parallax-content">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" class="border">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any help? Please!?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your jQuery:

`jQuery(this).css({
        'margin-top': marginTop
      });`

To:

`jQuery(this).css({
        'transform': translateY(marginTop)
      });`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this works by placing the text centered and scrolling with the panel, but the panels don't scroll over the text like in my example. This scrolling part is the hard part of this that I can't seem to figure out.